# Is there a way to add a shard key to a collection on an already sharded Atlas MongoDB cluster from either the Atlas API or some other way?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-atlas

Is there a way to add a shard key to a specific collection an already sharded Atlas MongoDB cluster from either the Atlas API or some other way?

I know Terraform probably doesn't work for this case, but was wondering if that can be done via the Atlas API somehow or some other means besides going to the Mongo Shell and running commands.

Comment: Should be this one [Refine a Shard Key](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/sharding-refine-a-shard-key/)

Comment: Hi @WernfriedDomscheit , thanks for the suggestion on "refineCollectionShardKey" , I did find that besides "shardCollection" , but it doesn't look like we can call those commands via the Atlas API right?

Comment: No idea, I am not working with Atlas. But I would guess with Atlas you don't need to care at all about sharding.